# Aligning repeating background image with non-repeating one at the bottom of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a variable size container that has a repeating background tile that stretches to fill the container at any width. I need the height of the container to be such that it's always a multiple of the height of 1 tile - this is so that I can seamlessly align the bottom of the container with an 'end' tile that is the bg image of the following container.
I am trying to do it with jQuery but my code is not working...

NOTE: the repeating background MUST start from the TOP as there is another piece above that it joins up with (so the solution to set the background tile to repeat from the bottom is not applicable in this case - that'll just break it at the top)
I need the javascript to work properly, not change the CSS only.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nRe7R/1/

Here is the JS:

```
function seamlessBottomBg() {
    var container = $('#container1');
    var bgTileAspectRatio = 65/1163;
    var tileWidth = container.outerWidth();
    var tileHeight = tileWidth * bgTileAspectRatio;
    //calculate how many px high the 'cutoff' last bg tile is, if there is a cutoff part
    var cutOffTileHeight = container.outerHeight() % tileHeight;
    if(cutOffTileHeight !== 0) {
    container.css('padding-bottom', tileHeight-cutOffTileHeight+1+'px'); 
        }
    }
seamlessBottomBg();
```

and the CSS:

```
#container1 {
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url(http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v488/fishygirl/paper-repeating_zps52e98fe2.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 3em 10% 0;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
#container2 {
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url(http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v488/fishygirl/paper-bg-bottom_zps441e1bc3.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 3em 10% 0;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: So hope i understood it. :) so why not cut image that you have only 1 line and then repeat it.

Comment: Because there are holes in the side of the paper that also need to be there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you set the background image to `bottom` it will repeat upwards.  Not sure if that's what you want, but here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRe7R/2/)

```
#container1 {
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url(http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v488/fishygirl/paper-repeating_zps52e98fe2.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: bottom;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 3em 10% 0;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: It has to repeat from the top because there is another ripped piece of paper joining at the top (I didn't think to add it to the fiddle, sorry). I am using the rule you put in there at the top already.

Answer (score 1):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/jtZwL/) *(Try resizing)*

Add these rules:

```css
#container1 {
  background-size:center bottom;
}

#container2 {
  background-size:center top;
}

@media (min-width:1024px) { /* 1024px is based on the image's width */
    #container2 {
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Comment: It has to repeat from the top not the bottom, because there is another ripped piece of paper joining at the top (I didn't think to add it to the fiddle, sorry). I am using the rule you put in there at the top already.

Comment: You can't expect both top and bottom to align. As a workaround, you can edit your bottom image so the part coming out to the right isn't there. This would make everything look aligned at the bottom.

Comment: I'm not expecting it to do that with pure CSS, have you looked at the JS? I am trying to set the height of the container with the repeating tile to be an exact multiple of whatever the tile height is at that window size. Or is there something wrong with my logic?

Comment: @b4rbika looks like you should redesign your background images, that will save you much code and make things less complicated.